# i am getting an error "An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information"

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

i am using `firebase` email and password credentials for log in -

```
if driverNameTextField.text == "" && passwordTextField.text == ""{
        AppUtils.showAlert(title: "Alert", message: "Please enter correct user name and password", viewController: self)
    }
    else{
        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail:userName.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!) { (user, error) in

            if error == nil{

                let revealController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SWRevealViewController") as! SWRevealViewController
                self.present(revealController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
            else {
                AppUtils.showAlert(title: "Alert", message: (error?.localizedDescription)!, viewController: self)

            }
        }
```

Here is the image

[image]

Comment: Why are you checking `driverNameTextField.text` and then using `userName.text`?

Comment: I am facing same problem. have you got any solution?